# How to remove row of data-frame based on duplicate date and ID

Tags: r, date, duplicates

I'm trying to remove an erroneous duplicate from my dataframe where the duplicate rows (e.g. Patient IDs 1 and 3 below) have no information (NA) in them.

The duplicates that need to be removed always occur first in the pair, so I was thinking of somehow using that information to remove them.

Have simplified the data below to reduce the problem a bit (NOTE: I am looking for a function that can remove multiple duplicates like this in a large dataset without having to identify them by hand):

[image: Click here for mock dataset]

I have been trying to work off the below code thus far:

```
test <- ea2[!duplicated(ea2[,c("PatientID", "SessionDate2")]),]
```

but this of course just removes the second duplicate row for patient IDs 1 and 3, which I need to keep in the dataset.

Comment: You may need `ea2[!(duplicated(ea2[,c("PatientID", "SessionDate2")]|duplicated(ea2[,c("PatientID", "SessionDate2")], fromLast = TRUE),]`

Answer (score 0):

> The duplicates that need to be removed always occur first in the pair

Relying on incoming row order is not advised, because it can change, especially when [pulling from a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053/111719).

Could you drop the rows with worthless information, and then use your `duplicated()` code?  If so, I like [`tidyr::drop_na()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/drop_na.html).

```r
ea2 <- tidyr::drop_na(ea2, PatientID)
ea2 <- tidyr::drop_na(ea2, SessionDate2)
```